# system.log: Warning: DOMXPath: :query() Invalid expression in /html/lib/Pelago/Emogriphier.php

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail, order-email

I keep seeing the following lines in var/log/system.log after each transaction email is sent:

> 2015-10-12T00:11:12+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid
>   expression  in /html/lib/Pelago/Emogrifier.php on line 326 
>   2015-10-12T00:11:12+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid
>   expression  in /html/lib/Pelago/Emogrifier.php on line 326 
>   2015-10-12T00:11:12+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Invalid argument supplied
>   for foreach()  in /html/lib/Pelago/Emogrifier.php on line 329 
>   2015-10-12T00:11:12+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid
>   expression  in /html/lib/Pelago/Emogrifier.php on line 326 
>   2015-10-12T00:11:12+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid
>   expression  in /html/lib/Pelago/Emogrifier.php on line 326 
>   2015-10-12T00:11:12+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Invalid argument supplied
>   for foreach()  in /html/lib/Pelago/Emogrifier.php on line 329

Someone knows what could cause this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> As the comment in the class definition states - This class provides
>   functions for converting CSS styles into inline style attributes in
>   your HTML code.

Looking at the calls of `emogrify()` method we discover that it is called by `_applyInlineCss()` method which is in turn called by `getPreparedTemplateText()` method defined in `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Abstract`.

The issue occurs when an invalid expression is passed to `$xpath->query()` also making `$nodesMatchingCssSelectors` invalid thus triggering the second error.

In my case, I had this issue in the `new-account.phtml` template that was using `{{inlinecss file="email-inline.css"}}` and in which at some point I had something like:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fa-spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
            transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

The issue was occurring when Emogriphier library tried translate `100%` into path: `$nodesMatchingCssSelectors = $xpath->query(`100%`)`. Because `100%` is not a valid selector the error is triggered.

```
/**
 * Right now, we support all CSS 1 selectors and most CSS2/3 selectors.
 *
 * @see http://plasmasturm.org/log/444/
 *
 * @param string $paramCssSelector
 *
 * @return string
 */
private function translateCssToXpath($paramCssSelector) {
```

A little bit late but hope this helps. :)